# Mask the passwords in log messages using MDC or Any Filters in spring boot without using logback.xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I have to mask the passwords in log messages without using logback.xml file in spring boot.

sample Log:
LOGGER.info("user password : {}", pwd);

expected Output:
2019-11-26 18:27:15,951 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  com.test.controller.TestController - user password: ***********

I able to achieve the same using logback.xml file. as shown below.
but without logback file need to do using application.properties configuration file in spring boot.

Note: Don't use log4j xml file. we should using slf4j or MDC or any filters and application.properties

```
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.test.config.MaskingPatternLayout">
                <patternsProperty>(SSN)</patternsProperty>
                <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.test" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Is it possible to achieve this without using logback.xml file and log4j.xml file?

can we able to mention the pattern layout java class in application properties file instead of mentioning the same in logback.xml file?
" in the above example, I have mention the java file in logback"

added MaskingPatternLayout for reference:

```
package com.test.config;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

@Component
public class MaskingPatternTest extends PatternLayout {

    private String patternsProperty;
    private Optional<Pattern> pattern;

    public String getPatternsProperty() {
        return patternsProperty;
    }

    public void setPatternsProperty(String patternsProperty) {
        this.patternsProperty = patternsProperty;
        if (this.patternsProperty != null) {
            this.pattern = Optional.of(Pattern.compile(patternsProperty, Pattern.MULTILINE));
        } else {
            this.pattern = Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        final StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(super.doLayout(event));

        if (pattern.isPresent()) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.get().matcher(message);
            while (matcher.find()) {

                int group = 1;
                while (group <= matcher.groupCount()) {
                    if (matcher.group(group) != null) {
                        for (int i = matcher.start(group); i < matcher.end(group); i++) {
                            message.setCharAt(i, '*');
                        }
                    }
                    group++;
                }
            }
        }
        return message.toString();
    }

}
```

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you want to use advanced logging features (other than setting log levels), you have to use logging-library specific configuration, such as `logback.xml` for Logback, `log4j.xml` for log4j and so on.

However, Logback does have an API you can call. For example, you can set up your `ConsoleAppender` with beans:

```java
@Bean
public LoggerContext loggerContext() {
    return (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
}

@Bean
public MaskPatternLayout maskPatternLayout(LoggerContext context) {
    MaskPatternLayout layout = new MaskPatternLayout();
    layout.setPatternsProperty("(SSN)");
    layout.setPattern("%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n");
    layout.setContext(context);
    layout.start();
    return layout;
}

@Bean
public LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> maskEncoder(MaskPatternLayout layout) {
    LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder<>();
    encoder.setLayout(layout);
    return encoder;
}

@Bean
public ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> maskConsoleAppender(LoggerContext context, LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> maskEncoder) {
    ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = new ConsoleAppender<>();
    appender.setContext(context);
    appender.setEncoder(maskEncoder);
    appender.start();
    return appender;
}
```

Now you could create your own `LoggerFactory`:

```java
@Component
public class MaskLoggerFactory {
    private final Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender;

    public MaskLoggerFactory(Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender) {
        this.appender = appender;
    }

    public org.slf4j.Logger getLogger(String name) {
        Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
        logger.addAppender(appender);
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.setAdditive(false);
        return logger;
    }

    public org.slf4j.Logger getLogger(Class<?> cls) {
        return getLogger(cls.getName());
    }
}
```

And after that you can autowire `MaskLoggerFactory` to get a proper `Logger`. However, this doesn't make things easier to use, and if your only justification is to avoid creating a separate XML file, I would encourage you to keep using that XML file.

Comment: Thanks so much for this approach. But ,while creating the autowire for MaskLoggerFactory , getting the bean initialization exception.

`
@RestController
public class TestController {
 
 @Autowired
 private static MaskLoggerFactory maskLoggerFactory;
 
 private final static Logger logger = maskLoggerFactory.getLogger(TestController.class);
`

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController' defined in file TestController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
`